# Including ZendX Jquery in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

How to add a ZendX Jquery library in zend bootstrap file ? my following code seems not working properly.

```
protected function _initViewHelper()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the problem with you code is that, you need to define an Action Helper object. The following code might solve your problems

```
protected function _initViewHelper()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->addHelperPath('ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/', 'ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper');

    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
}
```

Hope this will helps for you ;-)